# simplify implicit differentiation equation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, implicit-differentiation

I am a Calculus 2 student. I am doing implicit differentiation and I want to know the fastest way to simplify this and find y'. My online algebra calculator fails to ever solve problems the easy way. Hoping a math pro on here could show me "the easy way".

$$
\frac{x+y+y'}{xy}=e^{7x-y}(7-y')
$$

$$
=
$$

$$
\frac{1}{x}+\frac{y'}{y}=7e^{7x-y}-y'e^{7x-y}
$$

$$
y'=?
$$

Adding and subtracting messy fractions is never fun. Help friends :)

Comment: there is a typo in your equation

Comment: Is $x+x$ a typo? You have also split the fraction on the LHS incorrectly.

Comment: yes thanks its been corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

multiplying by $$xy$$ we get
$$x+y+y'=xye^{7x-y}(7-y')$$ multiplying out:
$$x+y'+y=7xye^{7x-y}-y'xye^{7x-y}$$
$$y'+y'xye^{7x-y}=7xye^{7x-y}-x-y$$
$$y'(1+xye^{7x-y})=7xye^{7x-y}-x-y$$
therefore
$$y'=\frac{7xye^{7x-y}-x-y}{1+xye^{7x-y}}$$

Comment: The OP has modified their question, hence you should change your answer a bit.

Comment: it is corrected, instead of $2x$ it is $x+y$ now

Comment: and my Point is going down now?

Comment: Between step 4 and 5 I notice that you ended up with a single y' and then a 1+(stuff) in the denominator. Can you articular what happened there? Did you simply take the derivative?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner sorry, I leant on the (un)-upvote button by mistake

Comment: @user2355058 He factored $y'$, ie. $$y' + y'xye^{7x-y} \equiv y'(1+xye^{7x-y})$$ at which point you can divide

Comment: yes i have inserted this step

Comment: Ah. the old elementary algebra. All that application makes ye' forget the ol' 6th grade math.

Comment: Can be written as $$y'=\dfrac{7 e^{7 x} x y-e^y (x+y)}{e^{7 x} x y+e^y}$$

Comment: yes Algebra is very old, some of thousend years

Comment: and from where Comes the $e^y$?

Comment: When I said "the old", Its a term of endearment in english. Something forgotten, but obvious. Its a figure of speech.

Comment: ok i see it, a Little bit simplier

Comment: send all your Algebra Problems to us

Comment: you guys are righteous and true

Comment: it is clear enough now?